# Using Graphs/Graph Similarity as Features for a Learner

Tags: graph-theory, machine-learning, network-modeling

I'm working to construct a learner than can recognize whether two vertices in a property graph (digraph, vertices and edges can have arbitrary keys/values) modelling a social network in fact represent the same person. I want to use the structure of the graph local to two vertices, compare those structures, and use the similarity as a feature.

I've had trouble finding related work. Light review of the literature leaves me stuck on graph methods - eg, Bayesian networks and graphs-as-learners- as opposed to learning graph-based domains. Are there any good resources I'm missing, or maybe suggested methods?

Comment: this question might be better suited to metaoptimize, but we do have some ML folks here who might be able to help out.

Comment: Thanks @Suresh- it looks like the QA side of metaoptimize is down right now, but I'll run it past them as well.

Comment: Have you checked out the following, along with other works by Lise Getoor? http://linqs.cs.umd.edu/basilic/web/Publications/2007/bhattacharya:tkdd07/bhattacharya-tkdd.pdf From what I remember she seems to focus on exactly these problems/techniques

Comment: Thanks @Lev, this looks like a great lead. I'd been viewing the problem from the name disambiguation angle, but entity resolution is probably more appropriate.